# EHCache for storing PreparedStatements

Tags: java, caching, prepared-statement, ehcache

We have a complex application with extensive db usage. The app uses just plain JDBC connection and as I see most of the places we always recreate a PreparedStatement run the sql, even if we run the same sql several times.
There is a wrapper for the JDBC connection like

```
  public class ConnectionWrapper {
      protected Connection connection;

      public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql) {
        return connection.prepareStatement(sql);
      }
```

Without rewriting the whole application it seems to be a good idea to add a cache to the wrapper which stores the `PreparedStatement` per sql and we return the statement from cache. When we close the connection the we would also clean up the cache. 
Do you think it is a good idea to use something like EHCache programatically here?

Update:
The same connection is used during the whole session, and getting new physical connection would trigger cache clean up

Comment: I wouldn't worry about caching `PreparedStatement` as they are precompiled and then cached by the RDBMS (if your RDBMS supports it). If you're worrying about extensive DB usage, perhaps the data should be cached. If that's the case, why not?

Comment: I don't think a third-party cache is necessary here. You could simply store those in a Map<String, PreparedStatement>.

Comment: Buhake: Thanks, so you mean that even if I recreate the PreparedStatement then the connection returns something from the JDBC level cahce, right?

Comment: @slowy, bad advice. `PreparedStatement` can get closed, particularly if they are managed in a connection pool or by the RDBMS for inactive use.

Comment: The `PreparedStatement` returned can be from the cached `PreparedStatement` from the RDBMS, so you essentially cannot recreate it. You will need to see what your JDBC vendor provides in terms of `PreparedStatement` and JDBC level cache. That should not be your concern. You should be concerned about data and how to optimize your application to retrieve data faster and efficiently.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: Your first comment is true, but it implies, a prepareStatement will send the sql to the dbms (depending on the driver).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi : Your second comment: Yes, but this is not the case, as OP states, the app uses plain JDBC.

Comment: @slowy, the SQL query is sent to the RDBMS anyway. It's the RDBMS that manages the `PreparedStatement`. The `PreparedStatement` is compiled once so there's no need to worry about sending the SQL later since the RDBMS has reference to the precompiled statement anyway. In future, it just substitutes placeholders `?` with actual values before executing it.

Comment: @slowy, what do you think I'm talking about here? `PreparedStatement` is **only** found in the JDBC API. The internals of it should **never** be of concerned to the developer (**strictly** only the RDBMS vendors implementing the JDBC drivers). By saying you're using plain JDBC you're stating that you're not bypassing the JDBC API to get vendor specific database connectivity and resources.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Yes, if the SQL is the same, it's cached in the RDBMS. But the prepareStatement sends the SQL again to the backend (again, depending on the driver)? So each "prepareStatement" will have a call to the backend. This won't be the case, if you reuse the same PreparedStatement instance.

Comment: This seems to me that the best is to configure it at JDBC level and not do anything at application level

Comment: @slowly, you shouldn't worry about it as well. The `PreparedStatement` sends nothing to the backend. You, essentially, populate a precompiled `PreparedStatement` which gets executed by the RDBMS. This is managed by the RDBMS. Again, it shouldn't be the developer's worry. Besides, most JDBC implementations provides with connection pooling and resource management, which caters for this sort of stuff. I say again: worry about optimizing the query to get data faster and also, if one worries about extensive DB usage, cache the data.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I'm not using plain JDBC, the OP uses JDBC. And please read the Java API of java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(). To your "never be of concerne to the developer"-statement: There are different behaviors (Microsoft SQL Driver / jTDS), missing implementations (missing timeout implementations in Firebird Driver), etc.

Comment: @slowy, didn't I say in my **very first comment** *(if your RDBMS supports it)*? Why are you arguing? Have you ever read the JDBC Specification (such as the [JDBC 4.1 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1418910282_902eaf3b732fbaa16c4db6041c84bae0))? It's not just good to read the `java.sql.Connection` javadoc. Read chapter 11.6 (Pooled Connection, Pooled Statement) & chapter 13.2 (precompiled `PreparedStatement`) to see where I get my reference from. This is the **documentation** which RDBMS vendors use to implement JDBC API.

Comment: There is no connection pooling involved. And I cannot find any information about how the sql is sent to the DBMS in chapter 13.2?

Comment: I guess you didn't read chapter 11 (entitled "Connection Pooling") and you shouldn't worry about SQL being sent to the RDBMS. That is managed by the RDBMS itself. Even if you knew how it was sent, how will it benefit you since you have no access to it through JDBC? Also, how would you optimize a query already optimized by the RDBMS? You're focusing on irrelevant stuff that you have no access at all. For your sake, read the entire specification, it'll enlighten your knowledge in JDBC.